# Show tooltip constantly with Google Pie Chart (quick javascript tweak)

Tags: javascript, charts, tooltip, pie-chart

I am interested in using a google pie chart and need it to display all the tooltips constantly. At the moment they come up individually on hover, just wondered if it's possible to do that by altering the js slightly?

Google says that you can use tooltip.trigger with either 'focus' which displays with hover or 'none' obviously to display nothing, but theres no function for show all

Heres the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Toe',     38],
          ['Jam',      22],
          ['Earl',  2]
        ]);

        var options = {
          legend: 'none',
          lable: 'none',
          is3D: true,
          pieSliceText: 'none',
          slices: [{offset:0.1}, {offset:0.1}, {offset:0.1},],
          chartArea: {left:70,top:50,width:140,height:140},
          colors: ['#99C9FF','#B7B7B7', '#CCC'],
          pieSliceBorderColor: '#999',

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
</script>
```

Comment: You mean this, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975597/google-charts-how-to-always-shows-the-tooltip

Comment: I read that post amongst others before I posted here and it doesn't answer my question... it's not a duplicate unfortunately. Any help greatfuly received

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the tooltips constantly if you use the follwing option:
`tooltip: { trigger: 'selection' }`

But then you need to click the slice to get it initially.